# MVC 3 Model Binding To Half Of A Long Table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-binding, model

I am trying to bind to a rather large SQL database table with over 100 fields. I'm doing basic CRUD operations, and when it comes to editing, I've decided to split up the editing into two pages (Views), just to keep the page lengths manageable and user-friendly. I'm using MVC 3 (C#) with the Entity Framework to map the database.

My question - how do I bind to "half" of this table in each ActionResult? There are two issues - I am validating most of the inputs using a partial class and the MetadataType attribute. How do I split up the validations so that one page is not validating fields for the other? Secondly, how do I bind to only half of the properties of the table? Many are non-nullable and would trigger database errors if they attempted to bind without corresponding form inputs.

I know I could use [Bind(Include="...")] or [Bind(Exclude="...")] in my two ActionResults, but it seems pretty illogical and non-DRY to list 50 individual fields in an include or exclude tag. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered using a ViewModel class to represent the data that will be editable in that page? You could then use AutoMapper to handle the property mapping between your entity and your ViewModel.

Comment: This ViewModel class obviously couldn't inherit from the EDM class for the whole table (or it would still try and bind the fields from the "other half")... so how would it know to bind this class back to the table?

Comment: The Entity and the ViewModel are separate classes. One do not inherit from the other one. You have to manually map each property from one class to the other class. This is tedious work, but you can use AutoMapper to take care of the mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have misunderstood this... after testing it looks like the MVC model binding allows for partial binding after all.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have a number of options.  First, you're going to need dedicated View Models that are specific to your views.  It may seem to violate DRY to have to duplicate these properties in different models, but the reality is that View Models and Data Models serve two purposes, and thus are different concerns.  You need to keep them seperate.

You would only place the properties you're using in the view in the View Model for each View.

Second, if your data model is not conducive to gradual updates, then you will have to store the data from each view somewhere so that you can do a single update.

You could store it in a temporary table, or you could serialize the data and store it in a hidden field in the view.  The MVC Futures project provides a handy Serialize html helper that will help with that.  Either way, you will need to break things up so that you can do a partial edit.

Comment: It just seems to me that if I have to create temporary tables, then I might as well prep a long "Include" or "Exclude" list and do it as an ActionResult attribute.

Comment: @Sylver - Again, data models and view models are different concerns.  The correct way to do it is view models.  I know it seems like a lot of work, but in the long run it's more maintainable and more robust.